# How to make a sound when visiting a certain website (Mac)?

Tags: youtube, applescript, automator

I am trying to think of a creative way to break my Youtube addiction.

How would I create an annoying sound when I visit youtoube.com? I was trying to do this with Applescript, but I got nowhere, so I'm seeing if the internet can help. I mainly just need some way that I can be constantly checking my current website (Safari and/or Chrome) and trigger an event when I am on Youtube. I know how to play my sound, but not the site-checking portion. Preferably I could make this on Automator.

I know there are better ways to break a habit, but I really want to do it this way. I really hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will make an annoying noise if the front tab of either Chrome or Safari is on a URL containing the word "youtube".

** edit **  to make this work in automator:

- Click Actions in the top-left corner of the Automator window, then select Utilities in the Library.
- Choose 'Run AppleScript'
- Paste the code into the code editor box

(replace *all* code in the entry box)

```
on run
    set check to "youtube"
    repeat
        try
            tell application "Safari"
                set theURLs to URL of current tab of window 1
            end tell

        end try
        try
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                set theURLc to URL of active tab of front window
            end tell
        end try
        if check is in theURLs then
            tell application "System Events"
                beep
            end tell
        end if
        if check is in theURLc then
            tell application "System Events"
                beep
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end run
```

Comment: Eli Front, I recommend un-ticking this answer, because this is not a usable script in any practical or realistic sense.  manymachinesonix, sorry for the double-dosing of harsh criticism.  Would it be more helpful to prod you to identify one or two key elements in your approach that you would consider doing differently (even if you're not sure how just yet) ?  Or do you prefer being told what _must_ be done differently, and what _should_ be done differently ?  Then you could re-draft the script, improve the answer, and that tick will be meaningful to you and for others.

Comment: This does work in the AppleScript editor, but not in Automator. It comes up with this error: The variable theURLc is not defined.

Comment: Hi Eli,

I have modified the script and added instructions on how to make this work in automator, rather than AppleScript editor.

@CJK I'm think skinned - feel free to share how you'd tackle this.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn’t tackle this.  I would categorically declare that the OP’s objective _cannot_ be done.  By this, I mean there isn’t a method or implementation in AppleScript to do this sort of thing efficiently, safely, wisely or in any practical, useful, or usable way. In fact, I’ll submit this as an answer, because it is important.

Comment: This works well enough for me, and if it doesn’t satisfy anyone else’s needs, then it is easy to make variations.

Answer (score 1):

I would assert with confidence that this *cannot* be done.  By this, I mean there is no method nor implementation in AppleScript to do this sort of thing efficiently, safely, wisely or in any practical, useful, or usable way.

This includes:

- Any script involving an infinite repeat loop, particularly one with no code allowing a user to break out of it;
- Any implementation that utilises [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science));
- And especially any script that polls at a faster rate than the time it would take for the thing being polled to undergo a change in state.

Comment: What do you mean? I was able to get something to work well enough to satisfy my needs. Using either idle or possibly some configuration with run works just fine.

Comment: "Getting something to work" isn't the only criterion that you need to consider when assessing the suitability of something. I could sign my name using tomato juice, but that's not a good, sustainable, or reliable solution.  "Well enough" is precisely what I'm focussing on. The script submitted has an infinite repeat loop. That is a NO! It's consuming and hogging resources, and eventually, that is going to slow things down, stop other processes from working, and with enough time, just crash stuff. Idling is better, but it's still polling, and that's not good either.

Comment: You can, of course, use what you want. I (and someone before me) were just alerting you to serious concerns. I obviously have no idea what your level of knowledge or expertise is with scripting, programming, or computer science, so I would have been remiss _not_ to highlight these issues. As an experiment, you can run the submitted script as it is written in _Script Editor_ with the `Replies` pane open (change the variable names to avoid an error) for live feedback of operations. Does that seem a reasonable amount of work for this script to be doing and with no way out ? (Hint: no.)